# Single column bind like multi column in a drop down list in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

```
 <td>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbookname" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:DropDownList>                             
 </td>
```

and my code behind code is as shown below

```
  DataTable dtbookname = new DataTable();
        objRetailPL.status = 1;
        dtbookname = objRetailBAL.GetTypeNew(objRetailPL);
        if (dtbookname.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlbookname.DataSource = dtbookname;
            ddlbookname.DataTextField = "BookName";
            ddlbookname.DataValueField = "sno";
            ddlbookname.DataBind();
            ddlbookname.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
            ddlbookname.SelectedIndex = ddlbookname.Items.Count - 1;
        }
```

out put is

xxxx

yyyy

aaaa

bbbb

cccc

dddd

eeee

ffff

....

....

.....

.....

.....

zzzzz

like this but actually I want is

xxxx    yyyyy   aaaa bbbb ccccc

dddd    eeeee   ffff gggg  hhhh

....    .....   .... .... .....

....    .....   .... ....  .....

like this

I have this dropdownlist, and this is having more data so I want to show it in multi column in  dropdownlist how can I please help me....

Comment: Follow this article at CodeProject : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8348/Multiple-Columns-DropDown-for-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

DropDrownList control is not meant to have columns. If you want to use a control which supports columns, you will have to use ListView or DataGridView.

[Reference here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60f1eea7-14fd-4e78-aa5a-2c33ec017839/display-columns-in-drop-down-list?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

xxxx

yyyy

aaaa

Join multi rows in a single row as like

```
String s = "xxxx" + "yyyy" + "aaaa";
```